# Kivy installation python 2.7 windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I want to develop python 2.7 app using Kivy library on Windows 10, but I do not know how to install it. I have tried to install Cython,Pygame and then Kivy.But it did not work. I have reinstalled all these things like Cython,Kivy,Python... And now I want to install it from the beginning. How can I install Kivy?

Your answers will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy changed a little bit since 1.8.0, use the new instructions if you have pdf docs, or some kind of book. So... the default provider is sdl2 now(pygame isn't necessary). Also, there's no need for compiling since there are `wheels`, so even cython and mingw aren't necessary(if you don't code with them). The only thing you need is python installed correctly.

At first of all you should visit main page and especially [*documentation*](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html) where is described quite well what is needed and what you should install, yet still someone comes with missing dlls or something, therefore read it carefully. Or grab a [tool](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller).

But really, use the docs, most of the stuff is documented either in docs or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kivy)(examples, problems,...). No one's going to read it for you. :)